# How to display image in diamond shape in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

[image]

I want to display images in diamond shape when I am giving width and height 120 and apply the corner radiu. I am getting diamond shape approximately but not getting exact diamond shape so any one suggest me it helpful to me.

```
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width / 2
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: can you paste your code here.

Comment: self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width / 2
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: i applied above code and i mentioned width and height equals to 120

Answer (score 24):

If you have an image view and want to crop it to a diamond (rhombus) shape, you should:

- Create `UIBezierPath` in diamond shape;
- Use that as the `path` of a `CAShapeLayer`;
- Set that `CAShapeLayer` as the `mask` of the `UIImageView`'s `layer`

In Swift 3 and later, that might look like:

```
extension UIView {
    func addDiamondMask(cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY + cornerRadius))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX - cornerRadius, y: bounds.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY - cornerRadius))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX + cornerRadius, y: bounds.midY))
        path.close()

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = cornerRadius * 2
        shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
        shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

        layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
}
```

So, just call `addDiamondMask(cornerRadius:)` (where the `cornerRadius` is optional), on your image view.

```
imageView.addDiamondMask()
```

That yields:

[image]

For Swift 2 rendition, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38090824/4).

---

An alternate algorithm for rounding of corners might be:

```
extension UIView {
    func addDiamondMask(cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        let points = [
            CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY),
            CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY),
            CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY),
            CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.midY)
        ]

        path.move(to: point(from: points[0], to: points[1], distance: cornerRadius, fromStart: true))
        for i in 0 ..< 4 {
            path.addLine(to: point(from: points[i], to: points[(i + 1) % 4], distance: cornerRadius, fromStart: false))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: point(from: points[(i + 1) % 4], to: points[(i + 2) % 4], distance: cornerRadius, fromStart: true), controlPoint: points[(i + 1) % 4])
        }
        path.close()

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }

    private func point(from point1: CGPoint, to point2: CGPoint, distance: CGFloat, fromStart: Bool) -> CGPoint {
        let start: CGPoint
        let end: CGPoint

        if fromStart {
            start = point1
            end = point2
        } else {
            start = point2
            end = point1
        }
        let angle = atan2(end.y - start.y, end.x - start.x)
        return CGPoint(x: start.x + distance * cos(angle), y: start.y + distance * sin(angle))
    }

}
```

Here I'm doing quad bezier in the corners, but I think the effect for rounded corners is slightly better than the above if the diamond is at all elongated.

Anyway, that yields:

[image]

Comment: Wow its awsome... But its not taking corner radius.. How can i make corners rounded in this. ?

Comment: @SagarThukral - See revised answer for example of how to round the corners.

Comment: Its Awesome.. Thanks a ton for help.

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 5

```
extension UIView {
    func addDiamondMask(cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY + cornerRadius))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX - cornerRadius, y: bounds.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY - cornerRadius))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX + cornerRadius, y: bounds.midY))
        path.close()

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = cornerRadius * 2
        shapeLayer.lineJoin = .round
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round

        layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
}
```